# What are the Galactic Trade Network costs?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How are the costs of using the Galactic Trade Network (GTN) calculated?

I know that the length of the auction changes the cost on the Sell interface. But you get credits back if the item doesn't sell. I'm confused which costs are which, and which are combined, if any.

How is the initial cost calculated per each auction length (1 day, 12 horus, etc.)? Is it a straight percentage of the Buy Now price you set?

I think the cost when selling the item is immediately deducted once the item is put up for auction, correct? If so, if the item doesn't sell, is the same exact amount returned? Or only a portion of it? If a portion, how much of a percentage? Or is the returned amount a flat value?

If the item does sell, the e-mail you get says you sold the item and gives you a value that has a fee subtracted out. Is that fee in addition to the auction cost? How is the fee calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you pay to get an item to an auction is a deposit. And you get it back when the auction ends, whether successfully or not. If the item is sold, a commission is deduced from the credits you receive.

For a two-day auction, the deposit is 15 % of the asking price. The commission is 3 % of the price (Source: my own calculations based on 4 successful sales.)

For example, in the sale from the screenshot below, the asking price was 1800 credits, the deposit was 15 % of that, or 270 credits (it was a two-day auction) and the commision was 3 % of the price, or 54 credits. So, I received 1800 + 270 - 54 = 2016 credits.

[image: Mail message of a successfull sale]

Comment: You really get the deposit back if your item doesn't sell? Whats the point of the deposit then?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the point, but that's what "deposit" means and it's what actually happens too.

Comment: Ah, the deposit does not get refunded if you cancel your item early.

Comment: I believe the GTN commision has been changed from 3% to 6% by now.